# I am trying to build a formula field but its giving an error

Tags: formula-field

```
If(!IsBlank(Saved_Date__c),Abs(Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Saved_Date__c),
    If(!IsBlank(Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c),
       Abs(Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c),
       Abs(Cancellation_Requested_Date__c -Course_Deffered_Confirmed_Date__c ),
       Abs(Confirmed_Enrolled_Date__c - Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c )))
```

I have made a formula to give date average in the system but its giving an error please any help would be welcome.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error message would be very helpful, but didn't see anything in the syntax that looked off. Have you verified the spelling of each of the fields, one that comes to mind is Course_Deffered_Confirmed_Date__c, as I would expect it to be Course_Deferred_Confirmed_Date__c.

Comment: Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'If()'. Expected 3, received 4. Is the error coming up in the syntax

Answer (score 1):

`If` function can take 3 parameters and the construct looks something like this `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. YOu have defined 4 parameters inside your inner `if` condition. So remove one of the parameters and the formula field should save fine.